# Linear Programming -- Minimizing t

Tags: matlab, linear-programming

I am trying to solve the following problem in matlab but facing some difficulty.

> Min t
>       **s.t.**
>       t>= 0.0538λ_2 - 0.7071λ_1
>            t>= λ_1 - 0.3827λ_2
>        where 0<=λ_j<=1 for j=1,2

This is what I have so far:

```
f=[0;0;1]  
A=[-0.7071 0.0538 -1;
1 -0.3827 -1]  
B=[0;0]  
ub=zeros(2,1)  
lb=zeros(2,1)  
linprog(f,A,B,[],[],lb,ub);
```

This problem is taken from a research paper and in that the author solved the above problem and found optimal value of t=−0.12698. I am not getting the correct answer with my implementation. Can someone help me please. Also how can I specify in `linprog()` that I want to use the simplex method.

Comment: your lower bound and upper bound both set to zero...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you the correct result:

```
f=[1;0;0];  
A=[-1 -0.7071 0.0538;
-1 1 -0.3827]  ;
B=[0;0]  ;
ub=[inf 1 1]  ;
lb=[-inf 0 0]  ;
options = optimset('Algorithm','simplex');
xres = linprog(f,A,B,[],[],lb,ub,[],options);
```

Note that `linprog` expects your input in the format:

min x

s.t. Ax <=b

What I did here, is set the vector `x = [t l1 l2]`, so the first entry in your result vector `xres` corresponds with `t`. You can set the algorithm using the `optimset` function.

Also, you set lower and upper bounds for 2 of the 3 variables only, so matlab gave me some warnings in that regard. To be on the safe side, it is usually best to set 'dummy' limits for the unrestricted variables (i.e. here I set the upper limit of `t` to `inf`, and the lower limit to `-inf`). That way, you make sure the right bounds apply to the right variables.

Comment: Thanks! This gave the correct solution. I wanted to ask what if i wanted to make λ an element of set [0,1] i.e λ can only have value of 0 or 1. How would I set that in the bounds and inequalities.

Comment: @user1234: in short, you can't. At least not with purely linear programming. If you want to compute a few of these points it is probably easiest to update the constraint by hand, i.e. set the corresponding bounds to equal values (`ub = [inf 1 1], lb = [-inf 1 0]`), then check for the lowest result. If you want to do this for a lot of values and find the optimum of those, you'll need to look into integer optimization methods, such as simulated annealing or MILP.

Comment: @user1234: Whoops I should have noticed that there is actually a rather easy-to-use function for integer linear programming, which is what you are trying to do. Take a look here: http://nl.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/intlinprog.html . The syntax is very similar to the `linprog` syntax you've used so far.

Comment: the intcon vector  helps with that. Thanks for the link. I have one final question. is there anyway to put a constraint on the sum of two lambda values? say for example a problem has λ_1 and λ_2 and we want to set a condition such that sum of λ_1 and λ_2 is always 1.

Comment: Yes, you can set equality constraints in `intlinprog` by entering the appropriate values in `Aeq` and `beq`. In this case, `Aeq = [0 1 1]` and `beq = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

matrix A is incorrect set.
You need determined what variables where should be.

```
A=[-0.7071 0.0538 -1;
  1 -0.3827 -1]
```

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Yes, I have corrected this but still do not get correct result.